# Has the Syrian Government used barrel bombs with chlorine since Trump's airstrike?

Tags: united-states, international-law, syria, treaty, chemical-weapons

A few days ago, President Trump launched an airstrike against a Syrian airbase in response to the Syrian Government launching a Saren gas attack.  Today, Secretary of Defense Mattis said that further use of chemical weapons by the Syrian government would warrant further military action by the United States, regardless of how those chemical weapons were delivered, including by barrel bombs.

Now in the year 2016, the Syrian Government used barrel bombs approximately 36 times a day on average.  And it is my understanding that these barrel bombs often contain chlorine gas.  So I have two questions:

1. Does the use of chlorine gas violate the Chemical Weapons Convention?
2. Has the Syrian Government used barrel bombs with chlorine gas after Trump's airstrike?

I think the Syrian Governmebt has definitely used barrel bombs after Trump's airstrike, but I'm specifically interested in barrel bombs with chlorine gas.

Comment: Do you have any citations for the 36 chlorine gas bombs a day? I'd believe it if it was regular bombs, but I dont believe that they were chlorine bombs

Comment: @DavidGrinberg To be clear, the statistic is 36 barrel bombs a day, not 36 barrel bombs with chlorine a day.  But my understanding from news reports is that these barrel bombs often contain chlorine gas.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Fine, lets say its 10 chlorine gas filled barrel bombs a day. I don't believe that. Please provide a citation.

Comment: In what differs a barrel bomb from a normal bomb? Both are a metal shell filled with explosives.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg I'm just relaying what I heard from news reports.  I don't know if "often" means once a week, or once a month, or what.  But the 36 barrel bombs a day statistic comes from the Syrian Network for Human Rights.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Can you link to just one of these news reports? I've honestly never heard of Assad using barrel bombs filled with Chlorine gas _ever_. That  is why I'm being persistent about this.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg I got this information from TV news reports, but check out this report from February 2016, which says that the Syrian Government launched at least 58 chlorine gas attacks since March 2015: https://www.sams-usa.net/reports/a-new-normal-ongoing-chemical-weapons-attacks-in-syria/

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Here's an example of Assad using barrel bombs with Chlorine gas: http://www.cnn.com/2016/09/07/middleeast/syria-aleppo-chlorine-attack/index.html

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan That's full of weasel words: "alleged," "an activist told CNN," "suspected" and so on.

Comment: That should read *alleged* attack. This question also contains unsubstantiated opinions, but it still got 4 upvotes. This is yet another example of the blatant hypocrisy here on Politics.

Comment: @Sjoerd in that aspect they are not different, but a) barrel bombs do not fit airplanes mounting points so they are thrown from helicopters and so they are not good against positions with a minimum of AA capability and this b) makes them better for civilians targets, and either for this reason or because Al-Assad specifically wants to target civilians, they are mostly used against civilians (which is most of the reason of the polemic about it). Also, there is the issue that in many cases they have been used to deliver chemical agents; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_bomb#Syria ...

Comment: ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_bomb#Reactions and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_of_chemical_weapons_in_the_Syrian_Civil_War

Comment: @SJuan76 if anything a bomb dropped from a helicopter is **more** accurate than the same bomb dropped from an airplane and by your logic we should be aplauding the humanitarian initiative of the assad regime's use of semi-guided munitions.

Comment: @easymoden00b You are completely missing the point, helicopters are far more sensible against AA so they can only be hover over soft (AKA civilians) targets.

Comment: @SJuan76 False conjecture.  Did you know that during **six months** of conflict in Mosul **one** helicopter has been shot down?  No?  Well now you do.  To claim that helicopters can only fly over civilian targets is absurd, at best.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Does the use of chlorine gas violate the Chemical Weapons Convention?

Yes. The use of any toxic chemical or choking agent whatsoever as a weapon---[even tear gas](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/morning-mix/wp/2014/08/14/tear-gas-is-a-chemical-weapon-banned-in-war-but-ferguson-police-shoot-it-at-protesters/?utm_term=.6c75e7c90168)---is prohibited. (Chlorine gas is *not* a controlled substance under the CWC however, meaning that there is no explicit provision against producing or stockpiling for legitimate purposes.)

> 2. Has the Syrian Government used barrel bombs with chlorine gas after Trump's airstrike?

No specific attack of this nature has been documented. An up-to-date table of reported chemical weapon attacks in the Syrian Civil War can be found [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_of_chemical_weapons_in_the_Syrian_Civil_War#Reported_chemical_weapons_attacks).

Comment: Usage of chlorine is not a violation of chemical weapon, according to CNN's Anderson Cooper 360.

Comment: @DylanCzenski Depending on the exact quote, it sounds like Anderson Cooper and/or his guest might be wrong. See paragraphs 52-53 in the "Report of the Independent International Commission of 
Inquiry on the Syrian Arab Republic" published by the UN: https://admin.govexec.com//media/un_aleppo_march1.pdf